# Обособление оборота "как спички"

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Правильно ли обособлен оборот "как спички"?

Мне кажется, что правильно в (1), неправильно в (2), а по поводу (3) есть сомнения, но я бы не стала обособлять.

(1) У нее всегда были самые модные тени, лаки и все такое прочее; тонкие, как спички, ножки на каблуках, шикарные шубки. [Владимир Бутенко. Анькины дети (1997)]

(2) У тебя не перелом был, у тебя была трещина, но ты же не жрала ничего, вот и были кости, как спички. [Павел Санаев. Похороните меня за плинтусом (1995) // «Октябрь», 1996]

(3) Юлька была тощая, ножки торчали, как спички, воткнутые в пластилин  [А. Матвеева. Завидное чувство Веры Стениной, 2015)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) *Tонкие, как спички*. Обычный сравнительный оборот, который по правилам выделяется запятыми

(2) *Кости были как спички*. По-моему, здесь "как спички" является частью сказуемого. Запятая не ставится.
Обороты с союзом как не выделяются запятыми, если оборот образует именную часть составного сказуемого или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла без сравнительного оборота) ([Розенталь § 115,](https://info.wikireading.ru/69367) п. 3)

(3) *Ножки торчали, как спички, воткнутые в пластилин*. По-моему, это обычный сравнительный оборот ("как" имеет значение "подобно").
Примеры:
*Руки его дрожали, как ртуть (Гоголь); Слова бесконечно тянулись одно за другим, как густая слюна (Салтыков-Щедрин);*

Comment: Юлька была тощая, ножки торчали, как спички.  Здесь запятая нужна. Юлька была тощая, ножки торчали, как спички, воткнутые в пластилин. А здесь при чтении вроде бы нет паузы перед оборотом (так как он сам содержит обособленный оборот), или это можно не учитывать?

Comment: По поводу пауз советую обратиться к @Sibylla. Я считаю, что здесь запятая нужна в силу формальных правил.

Comment: Я тоже предпочитаю формальные правила, но не могу найти что-нибудь подходящее на тему: сравнительный оборот внутри обычного обособленного оборота или, наоборот,  сравнительный оборот, содержащий другой обособленный оборот. Какие-то там были указаны ограничения.  В любом случае, спасибо за ответ.